# Do I need to run passenger-install-apache2-module after installing the libapache2-mod-passenger package?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian, passenger

If I install the passenger package via:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

do I still need to run:

```
 $ passenger-install-apache2-module
```

??

I'm using Debian Squeeze Unstable, Ruby 1.9.3, Apache2, and PostgreSQL 9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't as libapache2-mod-passenger is, basically, packaged result of passenger-install-apache2-module.